# Replicate PostgrSQL on-premise to Azure Database for PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, azure, cloud, database-replication

my client wants to replicate their PostgreSQL on-premise database to Azure for security resonse.
 How can I achive these the easiest way? Using Data Factory? I dont have access to client servers so Im looking for least configuration steps to perform.

Comment: Hi @Kamil Kwiaton, If the answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure suggest us use [DMS(Database Migration Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/dms-overview)) to migrate/replicate database. It provides many ways to help us migrate/replicate on-premise PostgreSQL to Azure SQL database for PostgreSQL.

Please ref these tutorials:

1. [Tutorial: Migrate PostgreSQL to Azure DB for PostgreSQL online using
   DMS via the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-postgresql-azure-postgresql-online-portal)
2. [Tutorial: Migrate PostgreSQL to Azure DB for PostgreSQL online using
   DMS via the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-postgresql-azure-postgresql-online)

Data Factory is mostly used for migrate the data between source and sink, won't copy the schema of the database.

But both of ways all need access to the source on-premise PostgreSQL database, without the access, we can't do the migration or replication.

HTH.

Comment: Do you know if I can replicate the database like every day or 24/7?

Comment: Hi @KamilKwiaton, schedule backup the database to Azure is an another question. Can you post a new question? I'm not familiar with PostgreSQL database. I need to do some research then give you the answer.

Comment: @KamilKwiaton No very sure, do you want to create a new backup or replace the old one?